Same code used in Internet Explorer navigate has different results
The issue that I'm facing is that in two different Excel macros in different Workbooks I use the Internet Explorer navigate with a string variable for the URL.
The codes are similar for the IExplorer creation and navigate part, they only differ in the string construction, but if we compare the strings in both cases (either through add watch or copy/paste) they are the same.
The string I'm assigning is a normal URL which is made of several strings put together.

For workbook A this string is composed of several calls and responses that help building the final string.
For workbook B, parts of the string were written in cells and then used to build up the string to make a call already with the workbook A final string.

Everything works correctly except in workbook B when navigating to the complete URL it doesn't transfer the whole URL, it omits a last part which is a "query" part like this "?type=ST" but the dataurl does have the complete string.
Now the best part, if I write the complete string for the URL:
IE.Navigate "https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl?Mod=search"
it works and navigates to that complete URL (this is an example)
This is the code being used:
Function calling(dataurl As String) As String

Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Dim htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Application.StatusBar = "Setting up..."
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate dataurl

Application.StatusBar = "Calling server..."
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:03"))

    Do Until IE.readyState = 4 
        IE.Refresh2 (3)
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    Loop
   calling = IE.document.body.innerHTML
   
   IE.Quit
  Set IE = Nothing
  
  Application.StatusBar = ""
End Function

I've tried different browsers for this but IExplorer in the end came through.

Have you tried making IE visible so you can see what's going on?  If I had to guess, the problem may be with whatever code is running your sub calling

Yes, I've analyzed that step-by-step but I came to no conclusions regarding why it doesn't navigate to the full URL from the "dataurl" string variable.

If I create a visible instance of IE and navigate to that full URL, it redirects me to a page with "This Stencil app is disabled for this browser."  So it looks like what you want to do at that site is no longer supported for IE.

Thanks for your input Tim. The issue is not the URL itself. As I've stated above the same "dataurl" string works for workbook A but not for workbook B when the code is the same. What is happening that removes the "query" ("?=Mod&Type" for example) part from the navigate command.

When testing I did see that it sometimes redirected from https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl?Mod=search to https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl

That's exactly the issue with workbook B when running that code, Workbook A applies the full URL to the navigate pane without any issues. Both VBA projects have the same libraries/references, so I'm trying to understand what might be the issue. other exmple mght be "https://finviz.com/screener.ashx?v=111&f=exch_amex" to see if it removes everything from the "?" onwards.

If it's exactly the same code I can't see how it would make a difference whether it's run in one workbook or the other...  Unless there's some other code in either workbook which is affecting the outcome.

Found the issue! The text I had in the cells to form the string was "Appl", when I turned it to "aapl" (lowercase) the navigate command in the internet explorer inserted the complete URL as intended.
So, must be mindfull of Upper and lower case when passing the URL to navigate.
Tim thanks for your input!

If you changed the string from "Appl" to "aapl" then you haven't just changed the case ... the second char is different.

Sorry, it was a mistype in the comment... it's the lower case issue.
